# Does my ISP router have connectivity to the ISP when in bridge mode?

Tags: networking, router, internet

I have a fiber internet setup. A fiber cable comes directly into my house and terminates in a router provided by the ISP. I will refer to it as the ‘ISP router’ from here on out. I have however placed the ISP router in bridge mode and configured my own router which now actually provides the internet to me. So the actual internet connection is from my router, not the ISP router.

The ISP router has a feature called "ITMS server – CWMP" or something. I am clueless as to what it is and I did not understand much from internet searches. There are several parameters hard-coded therein. Some parameters are like URLs and others some usernames and passwords. I think it enables my ISP to manage the device from their end or collect useful data from it.

Does this ITMS CWMP server or whatever remain active (or work normally) when the ISP router on which it is enabled no longer gets direct internet from the ISP? Since this device is in bridge mode my router gets the actual internet.

Comment: Your actual internet comes from the ISP.  All your bridged mode is doing is allowing your main router to use the ISP assigned external IP address. I do that as well for VPN access to my systems. The ISP still controls their modem - you do not.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Question. Does this itms cwmp server or whatever remain active (or work normally) when the ISP router on which it is enabled no longer gets direct internet from ISP. Since this device is in bridge mode my router gets the actual internet.

Possibly yes. The real answer is "it depends *a lot* on how the specific ISP implements it"... but in general, "connectivity to ISP" is a very different thing from "connectivity to Internet". CWMP/TR-069 traffic most likely *doesn't go* over the Internet at all.

Your fiber connection to the ISP is more complex than just Internet access – it often carries several VLANs over the same physical line, each of which connects the router to a different network. *One* of those VLANs is the Internet, but there is usually another completely isolated network for management traffic (CWMP etc), and sometimes more VLANs for IPTV traffic or VoIP traffic. Each VLAN can be independently "bridged" or "routed".

Depending on device, "bridge mode" will most likely bridge *just* the 'Internet' VLAN, but will have no effect on the 'Management' VLAN, which is still terminated at the router.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the underlying concept.  There are 2 connections one for internet and other for voice in the ISp router. Yes, you are right. I can only bridge internet, nothing else.

Answer (score 7):

You are seeing the
[TR-069](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TR-069):

> Technical Report 069 (TR-069) is a technical specification of the Broadband Forum that defines an application layer protocol for remote management and provisioning of customer-premises equipment (CPE) connected to an Internet Protocol (IP) network. TR-069 uses the CPE WAN Management Protocol (CWMP) which provides support functions for auto-configuration, software or firmware image management, software module management, status and performance managements, and diagnostics.

This protocol is used by the router to connect to an auto-configuration
server, presumably run by your ISP.
TR-069 defines an application layer protocol for remote management of
end-user devices. It provides the communication between customer-premises
equipment (CPE) and Auto Configuration Servers (ACS).

I would think that it is likely that the ISP modem will contact the
configuration server of the ISP when it is booting.
I would also think that further contacts wouldn't be required
after the boot when the router is in bridge mode.

For more authoritative information you should contact your ISP Support.

Comment: Before posting here I asked this query as a general tech query to ISP but their technician who eventually contacted me said that he can only handle issues related to internet connection matters like no internet or speed issue etc. He did not have any idea about this topic. So I thought of just asking here. Thank you for your help.